# new access token after login

Tags: authentication, google-api-js-client

I am using goggle ontap for login and it is working fine. But that google access token expires after 1 hour. Want to get a new token without forcing login screen after it expires. As per the documents it shows GoogleUser.reloadAuthResponse() to use but that is deprecated.